# I created a new branch but for some reason GitHub is showing 2

Tags: git, github

I added a new branch but for some reason it created a duplicate is this a normal behavior or should I be concerned ?

[image]

I used

```
git branch PayloadGenerators
git checkout PayloadGenerators
git add .
git push origin PayloadGenerators
```

Comment: What behavior were you expecting? Because to me, this just looks like you've made a branch locally, added some stuff, then pushed it up to GitHub where it's there (remote) which is normal imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub makes a distinction between a "branch" and an "active branch".<sup>1</sup>  The GitHub web page displays (a) some of your branch names, and (b) some "active" branches.  If you have one non-default branch and GitHub considers it "active", you will see it twice, so this is entirely normal.

---

<sup>1</sup>An "active branch" is, [according to the GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-branches-in-your-repository/viewing-branches-in-your-repository), one where:

> ... anyone has committed to within the last three months, ordered by the branches with the most recent commits first.

Note that Git itself makes no such distinction, but it doesn't really matter, since branch names in Git are entirely unimportant (except, perhaps, to you, if you're a human).